# feature idea: user's guest book

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page

I was thinking of LinkedIn and their recommendation system. This is a different website of course but I was thinking that having the possibility to leave a "thank you [...]" that would stay written in hard stone to users who really helped us would be great.

Comment: **Just give them a bounty.**  It's written in stone and uses the existing reputation system instead of creating a new one based on number of "thanks".

Comment: You need reputation to give a bounty, and that's not the same since you can get help from different way than just asking an official question.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that would add any real value to StackOverflow. It would have no place in the interface. Would clutter user profiles, AND would add one more source of spam.

I think user would use that to relieve their frustration against somebody who closed their answer or whatever else he did to them. That would be one more source of text to "moderate", and one unnecessary source of text to moderate.

And after all, what would it add? I mean OK, I could see I helped people... but I can already see that by having accepted answers / upvotes / bounties / comments. Do we really need a wall for this?

Comment: Weren't the moderators just saying that there's not enough work to go around...? :P

Comment: @animuson I know right! I'm sure they would dream to have to look at users' wall to find spam !

Comment: I would personnally like it. Linked-in has an "accept-mode" that the user has to accept the recommendation before it is posted, so there's no need for moderation. Regarding to the answers / upvotes / ... thing, I think this is really different. But however I can actually understand the global reaction of the community knowing that the simplest "hello" is off the chart.

Comment: @Sebas Linked is oriented around relations, others can "vouch" you, and thus recommendation systems and stuff like that. I just don't see how would that have a place on SO. I don't see how would it be useful at all to have comments on people wall.